# Closed operations of regular languages

Tags: nfa

Let x be a language over an alphabet,

INSERT(x) is the set of all strings obtained by adding exactly one more character into any one of the strings in x.

INSERT(x) = { azb : a,b ∈ ∑* and ab ∈ L and z ∈ ∑. }

Why is the set of regular languages closed under the INSERT operation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science theory, not programming

Comment: you should go to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @1010 No, that's for research-level questions. [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) deals with this kind of question.